# Add up multidimensional Sub Array Values by other Sub Array Values

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am working on a statistics Dashboard where I want to display some stats sorted by calendar weeks.

I'm getting the data in a multidimensional Array with this format:

```
Array
(
   [success] => 1
   [stats] => Array
      (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [year] => 2018
                [week] => 14
                [sum] => 18
                [country] => at
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [year] => 2018
                [week] => 14
                [sum] => 907
                [country] => de
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [year] => 2018
                [week] => 15
                [sum] => 2
                [country] => 
            )

        [3] => Array
            (
                [year] => 2018
                [week] => 15
                [sum] => 65
                [country] => at
            )

        [4] => Array
            (
                [year] => 2018
                [week] => 15
                [sum] => 237
                [country] => de
            )
        )

     )
```

My Problem is, that it's not only grouped by calendar week, but by country as well. What I want to get is an Array, which is grouped by calendar week. The `sum` should be the sum of every `sum` value with the same week. 
The Array I need should look like this one:

```
Array
(
   [success] => 1
   [stats] => Array
     (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [year] => 2018
                [week] => 14
                [sum] => 925
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [year] => 2018
                [week] => 15
                [sum] => 304
            )

       )

  )
```

The `country` is not needed anymore and it should be only 1 entry for each calendar week.

Comment: use the usual `foreach ($array as $row) { $new_array[$row['week']] }` combo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should do the trick

```
$newArray = [];
foreach ($firstArray['stats'] as $entry) {
    if (isset($newArray[sprintf('%d-%d', $entry['year'], $entry['week'])])) {
        $newArray[sprintf('%d-%d', $entry['year'], $entry['week'])]['sum'] += $entry['sum'];
    } else {
        $newArray[sprintf('%d-%d', $entry['year'], $entry['week'])] = $entry;
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

```
$newArray = [];

foreach ($stats['stats'] as $entry) {
   if (isset($newArray[sprintf('%d-%d', $entry['year'], $entry['week'])])) {
     $newArray[sprintf('%d-%d', $entry['year'], $entry['week'])]['sum'] += 
     $entry['sum'];
   } else {
     $newArray[sprintf('%d-%d', $entry['year'], $entry['week'])] = $entry;
   }
   unset($newArray[sprintf('%d-%d', $entry['year'], $entry['week'])]['country']);

}

$stats['stats'] = array_values($newArray);
```

@Rok D. Thanks for this one... I could adapt your example to perfectly fit my needs.

Comment: Almost there, but I guess I can adapt this one to make it work for my needs.
Can you explain me what the `sprintf('%d-%d'...` do?